# Consulting register with Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i get the date of the highest minutes for each user in the table?

I'm having trouble trying to solve this question, does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO watched_time (id,user_id, channel_id,minutes,`date`)
VALUES
(1,1,1,100.0,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.0'),
(2,1,1,180.0,'2021-01-02 00:00:00.0'),
(3,1,1,150.0,'2021-01-03 00:00:00.0'),
(4,1,1,110.0,'2021-01-04 00:00:00.0'),
(5,2,1,110.0,'2021-01-04 00:00:00.0'),
(6,2,1,140.0,'2021-01-05 00:00:00.0'),
(7,2,1,190.0,'2021-01-06 00:00:00.0'),
(8,3,1,170.0,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.0'),
(9,3,1,120.0,'2021-01-02 00:00:00.0'),
(10,3,1,130.0,'2021-01-03 00:00:00.0'),
(11,1,2,130.0,'2021-01-03 00:00:00.0'),
(12,2,2,130.0,'2021-01-03 00:00:00.0'),
(13,3,2,125.0,'2021-01-03 00:00:00.0'),
(14,1,2,110.0,'2021-01-05 00:00:00.0'),
(15,1,2,100.0,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.0'),
(16,2,2,120.0,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.0'),
(17,3,2,120.0,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

Comment: Why are you using a `datetime` type to store only `date` information?

Comment: Good question, this problem is a college task and they created the db, don't know why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY minutes DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, user_id, channel_id, minutes, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```